# Label не успевает обновиться в зависимости от текста

Tags: xcode, swift, label

Label не успевает обновиться в зависимости от текста. При занесении текста в label и последующего занесения ширины и высоты label в переменные, он записывает старые значения label. Как можно решить проблему?

```
labelHidden.text = "Какой-то текст..."
textWidth = labelHidden.bounds.width
textHeight = labelHidden.bounds.height
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что размеры Label вообще меняются после того, как присвоено новое значение текста? Возможно, изменение размеров происходит когда Label отрисовывается, т.е. на следующем кадре?

Comment: И как мне делать задержку на кадр?

Comment: не представляю себе, просто предположил.

Comment: это `UILabel` или просто `Label`? Полное имя класса какое?

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var labelHidden: UILabel!

Comment: Вообще можно попробовать с помощью анимации в блоке завершения получить новые размеры. А зачем Вам это нужно? Спрашиваю не просто так, может у Вас в корне подход неверный.

Answer (score 2):

Изменение текста UILabel не меняет его размеры. Перед тем, как записывать значения ширины и высоты, нужно обновить размеры с помощью метода **sizeToFit**:

```
labelHidden.text = "Какой-то текст..."
labelHidden.sizeToFit()
textWidth = labelHidden.bounds.width
textHeight = labelHidden.bounds.height
```

Answer (score 0):

В этом случае когда выставляете в storyboard объект любой не важно что это лейбл или кнопка, просто растяните его область до нужного вам размера зафиксируйте это дело в `constraints` и потом просто меняйте размер текста, а если не успевает тогда используйте потоки

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        // здесь выполняете все манипуляции 

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // здесь меняете текст   
       });
    });
```